# changing my forms get url params

Tags: yii

i made a simple form with `checkboxlist()` when i submit the form using **get** it goes to the next page, but the url is nasty looking.

```
http://mysite/dev/research/abc/all/?Abc[type]=N&Abc[type][]=1&Abc[type][]=2&Abc[type][]=3&yt0=Search
```

how would i change it to something like this?

```
http://mysite/dev/research/abc/all/?type=N&type[]=1&type[]=2&type[]=3
```

or if possible something nicer looking like

```
?type=1,2,3
```

note that i don't want `&yt0=Search` either

in my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new ABC;

        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$model
        ));
    }
```

in my view i have this

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                        'id'=>'shop',
                        'action'=>$this->createUrl('/modulename/abc/all'),
                        'method'=>'get',
                        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                    )); 


echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'type', $arr,
                        array('separator'=>'',
                             'template'=>'<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">{input}&nbsp;{label}</div>',
                              'uncheckValue'=>N,
                            )
);

echo CHtml::submitButton('Search', array('class'=>'btn btn-success'));

echo CHtml::button('Clear Filter', array('class'=>'btn btn-link', 'type'=>'reset')); 

$this->endWidget(); 
?>
```

## UPDATE:

figured it out. had to add **'name'=> 'type'**

but how do i remove **&yt0=Search**

```
echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'type', $arr,
                                            array('name'=> 'type',
                                                  'separator'=>'',
                                                  'template'=>'<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">{input}&nbsp;{label}</div>',
                                                  'uncheckValue'=>N,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [CHtml:button](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh2) to not post the `&yt0=Search`

```
<?php
                    echo CHtml::button('Search',
                        array(
                            'submit'=>array('/modulename/abc/all'),
                            'class'=>'btn btn-success'
                        )
                    );
                    ?>
```